# Few Errors, Couldn't Find the Bugs

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a few errors in my code. It says:

> moveDelay() does not exist in touchesBegan()

and it is saying that I should delete `override` from the last two override functions. I read that it could be because of a missing `},` but I could not find any errors. Sorry it's so long.
**All vars have been declared, I deleted them to get under the word limit.**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { 
    func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String){
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find music")
            return
        }
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
            backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


        begin.text = "Tap to Begin"
        begin.fontSize = 20
        begin.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.width/2, y: scene!.frame.height/2)
        begin.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        begin.zPosition = 2.0
        self.addChild(begin)
        Fading = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2), SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2)])
        begin.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Fading))

        HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(highscore)"
        HighScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.width/2, y: 120)
        HighScoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.addChild(HighScoreLabel)
        var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
        highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
        if (score > highscore){
            defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        }
        var HighScoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
        HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(HighScoreShow)"

        ScoreLabel.alpha = 0
        ScoreLabel.fontSize = 35
        ScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.width/2, y: 150)
        ScoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        ScoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        self.addChild(ScoreLabel)

        instruct.frame = CGRect(x: 270, y: 0, width: 150, height: 20)
        instruct.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        instruct.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 20)
        instruct.text = "Tap to Shoot"
        instruct.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view?.addSubview(instruct)

        let delay = 3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.instruct.removeFromSuperview()
        }


        MainBall.size = CGSize(width: 135, height: 135)
        MainBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2)
        MainBall.zPosition = 1.0
        MainBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: MainBall.size.width/2)
        MainBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        MainBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square
        MainBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pentagon
        MainBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square
        MainBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pentagon
        MainBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NonStop
        MainBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NonStop

        MainBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        MainBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        MainBall.name = "MainBall"

        self.addChild(MainBall)


            }

    func pentDelay(){

        let delay1 = 20.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay1))
        dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.pentTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("PentSpawn"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }

    }
    func circleDelay(){

        let delay2 = 40.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay2))
        dispatch_after(time2, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.circleTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("CircleSpawn"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }


    func moveDelay(){
        let delay1 = 30.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay1))
        dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            var left = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width/2 - 60, duration: 2.0)
            var right = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width/2 + 120, duration: 2.0)
            var moving = SKAction.sequence([left, right])
            self.MainBall.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moving))

        }

    }

    func NonstopPower(){
        NonStop.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
        var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))
        var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height))
        NonStop.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(PositionX), y: CGFloat(PositionY))
        NonStop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: NonStop.size)
        NonStop.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NonStop
        NonStop.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet
        NonStop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet
        NonStop.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        NonStop.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        NonStop.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        NonStop.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        NonStop.name = "NonStop"
        self.addChild(NonStop)
    }



    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if contact.bodyA.node != nil && contact.bodyB.node != nil{
            let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
            let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

            if((firstBody.name == "square") && (secondBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletSquare(firstBody, bullet: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "square") && (firstBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletSquare(secondBody, bullet: firstBody)
            }else if((firstBody.name == "pentagon") && (secondBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletPentagon(firstBody, bullet: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "pentagon") && (firstBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletPentagon(secondBody, bullet: firstBody)
            }else if ((firstBody.name == "circle") && (secondBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletCircle(firstBody, bullet: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "circle") && (firstBody.name == "bullet")){
                collisionBulletCircle(secondBody, bullet: firstBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "MainBall") && (firstBody.name == "square")){
                collisionBallSquare(secondBody, square: firstBody)
            }else if((firstBody.name == "MainBall") && (secondBody.name == "square")){
                collisionBallSquare(firstBody, square: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "MainBall") && (firstBody.name == "pentagon")){
                collisionBallPentagon(secondBody, pentagon: firstBody)
            }else if((firstBody.name == "MainBall") && (secondBody.name == "pentagon")){
                collisionBallPentagon(firstBody, pentagon: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "MainBall") && (firstBody.name == "circle")){
                collisionBallCircle(secondBody, circle: firstBody)
            }else if((firstBody.name == "MainBall") && (secondBody.name == "circle")){
                collisionBallCircle(firstBody, circle: secondBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "bullet") && (firstBody.name == "NonStop")){
                NonStopCollect(firstBody, bullet: secondBody)
            }else if((firstBody.name == "bullet") && (secondBody.name == "NonStop")){
                NonStopCollect(secondBody, bullet: firstBody)
          //  }else if((secondBody.name == "bullet") && (firstBody.name == "Ultimate")){
               // UltimateCollect(firstBody, bullet: secondBody)
        //    }else if((firstBody.name == "bullet") && (secondBody.name == "Ultimate")){
               // UltimateCollect(secondBody, bullet: firstBody)
            }else if((secondBody.name == "MainBall") && (firstBody.name == "NonStop")){
                NonStop.removeFromParent()
            }else if((firstBody.name == "MainBall") && (secondBody.name == "NonStop")){
                NonStop.removeFromParent()
        //     }else if((secondBody.name == "MainBall") && (firstBody.name == "Ultimate")){
               //  Ultimate.removeFromParent()
          //  }else if((firstBody.name == "MainBall") && (secondBody.name == "Ultimate")){
               // Ultimate.removeFromParent()
            }



        }

    }

    func NonStopCollect(NonStop : SKSpriteNode, bullet : SKSpriteNode){
        NonStop.removeFromParent()
        NonStopPowerBool = true
        bullet.removeFromParent()
        let delay4 = 10.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time4 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay4))
        dispatch_after(time4, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.NonStopPowerBool = false
        }

    }

   /* func UltimateCollect(Ultimate : SKSpriteNode, bullet : SKSpriteNode){
        Ultimate.removeFromParent()
        bullet.removeAllActions()
        var path = UIBezierPath()
        var dx = bullet.position.x
        var dy = bullet.position.y
        var rad = atan2(dy, dx)
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bullet.position.x, y: bullet.position.y), radius: 40, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: true, speed: 150)
        bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
    }*/


    func collisionBulletSquare(square : SKSpriteNode, bullet : SKSpriteNode){
        square.removeAllActions()
        square.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.2, duration: 0.2))
        playBackgroundMusic("Pop.mp3")
        score++
        ScoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        if (NonStopPowerBool == false){
            bullet.removeFromParent()
        let delay1 = 0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay1))
        dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        square.removeFromParent()
        }

        }
    }
    func collisionBulletPentagon(pentagon : SKSpriteNode, bullet : SKSpriteNode){
        pentagon.removeAllActions()

        pentagon.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.2, duration: 0.2))

        playBackgroundMusic("Pop.mp3")
        score = score + 2
        ScoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        if (NonStopPowerBool == false){
        bullet.removeFromParent()
            let delay1 = 0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay1))
            dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        pentagon.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
    func collisionBulletCircle(circle : SKSpriteNode, bullet : SKSpriteNode){
        circle.removeAllActions()

        circle.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.2, duration: 0.2))

        playBackgroundMusic("Pop.mp3")
        score = score + 3
        ScoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        if (NonStopPowerBool == false){
            bullet.removeFromParent()
        }
        let delay1 = 0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay1))
        dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        circle.removeFromParent()
        }
    }

    func collisionBallSquare(MainBall : SKSpriteNode, square : SKSpriteNode){
        hits++
        if (hits < 2){
            MainBall.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(2.0, duration: 3.0))
        }else if (hits>=2){
            squareTimer.invalidate()
            pentTimer.invalidate()
            circleTimer.invalidate()
            pentDelay()
            circleDelay()
            NonStopTimer.invalidate()
            gameStarted = false
            begin.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
            begin.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Fading))
            HighScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
//highscore
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
            highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            if (score > highscore){
                defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
            }
            var HighScoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(HighScoreShow)"
            MainBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            MainBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            square.removeFromParent()

        }
        square.removeFromParent()
    }
    func collisionBallPentagon(MainBall : SKSpriteNode, pentagon : SKSpriteNode){
        hits++
        if (hits < 2){
            MainBall.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(2.0, duration: 3.0))
        }else if (hits>=2){
            pentTimer.invalidate()
            circleTimer.invalidate()
            squareTimer.invalidate()
            pentDelay()
            circleDelay()
            NonStopTimer.invalidate()
            gameStarted = false
            begin.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
            begin.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Fading))
            HighScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
            //highscore
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
            highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            if (score > highscore){
                defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
            }
            var HighScoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(HighScoreShow)"
            MainBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            MainBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            pentagon.removeFromParent()

        }
        pentagon.removeFromParent()

    }
    func collisionBallCircle(MainBall : SKSpriteNode, circle : SKSpriteNode){
        hits++
        if (hits < 2){
            MainBall.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(2.0, duration: 3.0))
        }else if (hits>=2){
            circleTimer.invalidate()
            pentTimer.invalidate()
            squareTimer.invalidate()
            pentDelay()
            circleDelay()
            NonStopTimer.invalidate()
            gameStarted = false
            begin.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
            begin.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(Fading))
            HighScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2))
            //highscore
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
            highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            if (score > highscore){
                defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
            }
            var HighScoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(HighScoreShow)"
            MainBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            MainBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            circle.removeFromParent()

        }

        circle.removeFromParent()

        }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        if gameStarted == false{
            begin.removeAllActions()
            begin.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            begin.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2))
            circleTimer.invalidate()
            pentTimer.invalidate()
            squareTimer.invalidate()
            NonStopTimer.invalidate()
           // UltimateTimer.invalidate()
            NonStopPowerBool = false
            let delay3 = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time3 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay3))
            dispatch_after(time3, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.HighScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2))
                self.ScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.2)]))
                self.circleTimer.invalidate()
                self.pentTimer.invalidate()
                self.squareTimer.invalidate()
                self.squareTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: Selector("SquareSpawn"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                self.NonStopTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20.0, target: self, selector: Selector("NonstopPower"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
              //  self.UltimateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: Selector("UltimatePower"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                self.pentDelay()
                self.circleDelay()
                self.MainBall.removeAllActions()
                self.moveDelay()
                self.gameStarted = true
                self.MainBall.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.66, duration: 0.2))
                self.hits = 0
                self.score = 0
                self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"
                self.MainBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                self.MainBall.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.height/2, duration: 0.5))
                self.MainBall.runAction(SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width/2, duration: 0.5))
                self.MainBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            }
        }else{
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            begin.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2))
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
            highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            if (score > highscore){
                defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
            }
            var HighScoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            HighScoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(HighScoreShow)"


            var bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CircleBullet.png")
            bullet.position = MainBall.position
            bullet.zPosition = -1
            bullet.size = CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)

            bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bullet.size.width/2)
            bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet
            bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square
            bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pentagon
            bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square
            bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pentagon
            bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NonStop
            bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.NonStop
           // bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ultimate
           // bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ultimate
            bullet.name = "bullet"
            bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            self.addChild(bullet)
            let delay4 = 10.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time4 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay4))
            dispatch_after(time4, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                bullet.removeFromParent()
            }


            var dx = CGFloat(location.x - MainBall.position.x)
            var dy = CGFloat(location.y - MainBall.position.y)

            let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

            dx /= magnitude
            dy /= magnitude

            let vector = CGVector(dx: 2.0 * dx, dy: 2.0 * dy)

            bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)


        }
        }
    }


    func SquareSpawn(){

        let square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square.png")
        square.size = CGSizeMake(35, 35)
        square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: square.size)
        square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.square
        square.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        square.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        square.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        square.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        square.name = "square"


        let RandomPosNmbr = arc4random() % 4

        switch RandomPosNmbr{
        case 0:
            square.position.x = 0
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            square.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(square)
            break
        case 1:
            square.position.x = frame.size.width
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            square.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(square)

            break
        case 2:
            square.position.y = 0
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            square.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(square)
            break
        case 3:
            square.position.y = frame.size.width
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            square.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(square)
            break
        default:

            break
        }

        square.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(MainBall.position, duration: 3.0))
        let delay3 = 3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time3 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay3))
        dispatch_after(time3, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            square.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

    func PentSpawn(){

        let pentagon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pentagon.png")
        pentagon.size = CGSizeMake(35, 35)
        pentagon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pentagon.size)
        pentagon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pentagon
        pentagon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        pentagon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        pentagon.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        pentagon.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        pentagon.name = "pentagon"

        let RandomPosNmbr = arc4random() % 4

        switch RandomPosNmbr{
        case 0:
            pentagon.position.x = 0
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            pentagon.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(pentagon)
            break
        case 1:
            pentagon.position.x = frame.size.width
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            pentagon.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(pentagon)

            break
        case 2:
            pentagon.position.y = 0
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            pentagon.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(pentagon)
            break
        case 3:
            pentagon.position.y = frame.size.width
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            pentagon.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(pentagon)
            break
        default:

            break
        }

        pentagon.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(MainBall.position, duration: 2.5))
        let delay3 = 2.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time3 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay3))
        dispatch_after(time3, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            pentagon.removeFromParent()
        }

    }
    func CircleSpawn(){

        let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BlueCircle.png")
        circle.size = CGSizeMake(35, 35)
        circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.size.width/2)
        circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.circle
        circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        circle.name = "circle"

        let RandomPosNmbr = arc4random() % 4

        switch RandomPosNmbr{
        case 0:
            circle.position.x = 0
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            circle.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(circle)
            break
        case 1:
            circle.position.x = frame.size.width
            var PositionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            circle.position.y = CGFloat(PositionY)
            self.addChild(circle)

            break
        case 2:
            circle.position.y = 0
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            circle.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(circle)
            break
        case 3:
            circle.position.y = frame.size.width
            var PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            circle.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)
            self.addChild(circle)
            break
        default:

            break
        }

        circle.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(MainBall.position, duration: 2.4))
        let delay3 = 2.4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time3 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay3))
        dispatch_after(time3, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            circle.removeFromParent()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `circleDelay` has an opening `{`, then the `dispatch_after` has an opening `{` and closing `}`. But your `circleDelay` has no closing `}`. Therefore the following function declaration of `moveDelay` is happening in the scope of `circleDelay` and is not available outside that method scope.

There might be something else wrong with your code, but it is hard to tell since you do not properly indent your code, you not following the the regular naming guidelines, e.g. camel case for variable names.

**Aaaand** you posted too much code. Therefore take my first found error, fix that, properly indent your code and then come back and post a second question where you ask about **one** specific error.